# mysql 8 window function wrong results

Tags: mysql, large-data, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I have a problem with window functions in MySQL8 - they give incorrect results when applied to large tables (either: large number of rows or large number of columns).

Example:
Table: bureau.csv (1.7 mln rows) from https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-credit-default-risk/data

I run 3 simple queries changing only the number of rows of the table to be used and number of columns to be outputed. You can clearly see that the combination of large amount of rows and many outputed columns gives incorrect results of "count(*) over()" - the last column.

[high number of rows, low number of columns - result: OK;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTBZl.png)

[high number of rows, high number of columns - result: INCORRECT;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRA3d.png)

[low number of rows, hight number of columns - result: OK;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLNa4.png)

Ubuntu 16.04, 32GB of RAM

Many thanks for Your help! :)

Witold

```
my.cnf:
[mysqld]

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 26G
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
thread_cache_size = 50
innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT
local_infile=ON
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MEMORY
join_buffer_size=1G
temptable_max_ram=4G
tmp_table_size=4G
max_heap_table_size=4G
mysqlx_connect_timeout=99999
mysqlx_read_timeout=99999
mysqlx_write_timeout=99999
net_read_timeout=99999
net_write_timeout=99999
regexp_time_limit=99999
mysqlx_port_open_timeout=99999
windowing-use-high-precision=OFF
sort_buffer_size=4G
```

The code to run:

```
select a.*
from
(
select #b.sk_id_curr,
       b.*,
       count(*) over(partition by b.sk_id_curr) as counter
from (select * from bureau limit 10000000) b
) a
order by a.sk_id_curr desc
limit 100
;
```

edit:
[exlain and indexes picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/560J2.png)

And one more thing I noticed: in the "INCORRECT" picture all columns are incorrect (not only the last one) - compare to pictures with the "GOOD" result" (look at sk_id_curr).

As requested by Wilson Hauck: A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; SHOW CREATE TABLE bureau;
[part1](https://pastebin.com/raw/YRxVVjBH)
[part2](https://paste.ee/p/VbomS)

A sample 1000 rows on DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fzXsN6vFzidhanxeUjWkiB/0

The way I imported data to mysql:

**First** I replaced "blank spaces" in the csv with "NULL" in python:

```
import pandas as pd
bureau = pd.read_csv('../input/bureau.csv')
bureau.to_csv('../input/bureau2.csv',index=False,na_rep="NULL",header=True)
```

**Second** I used the code in mysql:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '../input/bureau2.csv' INTO TABLE bureau
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
;
```

Comment: Why it's wrong? MySQL docs cleary states a window function works on row "A window function performs an aggregate-like operation on a set of query rows. However, whereas an aggregate operation groups query rows into a single result row, a window function produces a result for each query row: "  source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **Unfortunately, we can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: @RaymondNijland the correct result of "count(*) over(partition by b.sk_id_curr)" for each row is the number of rows sharing the same b._sk_id_curr value.

Comment: @tadman the link to the data table was already provided, and the code is a classic "one liner" but I will provide it for You.

Comment: Inline code is vastly better than links. Thanks.

Comment: @tadman you're welcome. I can also provide instructions on how to import the dataset into MySQL. But I think the problem is not in the query or the dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure your hardware or operating system is a factor here. I'd suspect it's the partitioning that's set up differently. Can you replicate this without partitioning? That's not a lot of data for MySQL to handle so partitioning may be more trouble than it's worth here.

Comment: @tadman the problem is more general - I want to use partitioning in many queries, but the question is: is mysql reliable with window functions and how can I make them give correct results...

Comment: @WitekOleksiewicz Please post text results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT your query....;  and B) SHOW INDEX FROM bureau;

Comment: Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section
    temptable_max_ram=320M  # from 4G  for 1 percent of RAM
    tmp_table_size=320M  # from 4G for 1 percent of RAM
    max_heap_table_size=320M  # from 4G for 1 percent of RAM
    innodb_thread_concurrency=0  # from 2 throttle
    innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G  # from 26G for 80% of RAM
    innodb_change_buffer_max_size=10  # from 25 percent set aside
    # sort_buffer_size=4G   for default
    # join_buffer_size=4G  for default 

. with only 32G RAM, you had asked for 26G, 1G, 4G, 4G, 4G, 4G = 43G nothing for MySQL & OS?

Comment: @WilsonHauck YES, I know 43>32. I tested all kinds of values (started with smaller and kept increasing buffer sizes). As far as I'm concerned ORACLE is waisting both our times with introducing a buggy feature (window functions).

Comment: Hi I found that I get the same error as you. MySQL only just recently implemented Window Functions on version 8 so perhaps they still have bugs to work out. I've found that it gets the first ~200 rows correct (~100 data windows, returning 6 columns of data) but begins to give the incorrect results after that. I am using MySQL v 8.0.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version gave expected results for 8.0.11 for me (notice there are no longer any text blobs). You also need to disable --big_tables if you have it set for this to work.

```
CREATE TABLE `bureau` (
 `SK_ID_CURR` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `SK_ID_BUREAU` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CREDIT_ACTIVE` varchar(20),
 `CREDIT_CURRENCY` varchar(20),
 `DAYS_CREDIT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CREDIT_DAY_OVERDUE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DAYS_CREDIT_ENDDATE` varchar(20),
 `DAYS_ENDDATE_FACT` varchar(20),
 `AMT_CREDIT_MAX_OVERDUE` varchar(20),
 `CNT_CREDIT_PROLONG` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `AMT_CREDIT_SUM` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `AMT_CREDIT_SUM_DEBT` varchar(20),
 `AMT_CREDIT_SUM_LIMIT` varchar(20),
 `AMT_CREDIT_SUM_OVERDUE` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `CREDIT_TYPE` varchar(20),
 `DAYS_CREDIT_UPDATE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `AMT_ANNUITY` varchar(20),
 KEY `bureau` (`SK_ID_CURR`,`SK_ID_BUREAU`),
 KEY `bureau_i2` (`SK_ID_BUREAU`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

set session sql_mode='';
load data infile '/export/home/tmp/dag/git/mysql/bureau.csv' into table bureau columns terminated by "," ignore 1 lines;


select a.*
from
(
select #b.sk_id_curr,
       b.*,
       count(*) over(partition by b.sk_id_curr) as counter
from (select * from bureau) b
) a
order by a.sk_id_curr desc
limit 100
;
```

Comment: atDagW, no luck...https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NCMF.png, big_tables=OFF, since today 8.0.12

Comment: Weird... Ok, thanks for trying. I'll be persuing this.

Comment: Yes, I am, but only if I use --big-tables (on latest trunk), or big-tables or text blobs on 8.0.11. We're looking into it.

Comment: Witek, the observed behavior has been traced back to a bug and a solution has been found. Thank you for helping uncover this issue!

Comment: Thank You DagW :) I was trying to use MySQL in/for one of the current kaggle competitions but I switched to a different one now. But in the future I will definitely use MySQL again. Well because I kinda "worked it out" and because of the community (You and Willson) that was very helpfull. :) Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

```
temptable_max_ram=320M # from 4G for 1 percent of RAM 
tmp_table_size=320M # from 4G for 1 percent of RAM 
max_heap_table_size=320M # from 4G for 1 percent of RAM 
innodb_thread_concurrency=0 # from 2 throttle choking your server 
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G # from 26G for 80% of RAM 
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=10 # from 25 percent set aside 
# sort_buffer_size=4G for default 
# join_buffer_size=4G for default
```

with only 32G RAM, you had asked for 26G, 1G, 4G, 4G, 4G, 4G = 43G leaving nothing for MySQL & OS?

For additional assistance, check profile, Network Profile for contact info.

Comment: @Witek Oleksiewicz  Have any of the Suggestions been applied to my.cnf-ini?  Could you post recent complete error log (or last 400 lines)?

Comment: 'at' Wilson Hauck, Yes, I applied all your suggestions - that didn't help, I wasn't running out of memory - the table is not large enough. There are no errors - just the query output is incorrect... Correct me if I'm wrong - erros by default should be displayed at the console, yes? Im not a db guru - I just wanted to becomae a happy user... :)

Comment: @WitekOleksiewicz Please post TEXT RESULTS of SHOW CREATE TABLE bureau;  from your system.

Comment: 'at' Wilson Hauck, I've added the things You requested at the end of the OP. Thank You for your help. :)

Comment: @WitekOleksiewicz Any chance this will work?  Not tested.
select a.*
    from
    (
    select #b.sk_id_curr,
           b.*,
           count(*) over(partition by b.sk_id_curr) as counter
           FROM bureau limit 10000000) b
    ) a
    order by a.sk_id_curr desc
    limit 100
    ;   Sorry about the scrunch reformatting on Save Edits

Comment: atWilson, there is a syntax error, what is/was the intended change to my query? :)

Comment: If you had a table create for bureau and small load data sequence that could be used on https://www.db-fiddle.com, I would try to work out the syntax error where they indicate 8.0 can be tested.  Intended change was to reduce third level of data acquisition.  Also, I would be able to EXPLAIN SELECT   …; SHOW WARNINGS; to see what the optimizer did with rearranging the sequence of processing.

Comment: atWilson, Ive added a fiddle link in the OP :)

Comment: Great.  Are the results reasonable and accurate?

Comment: atWilson, on this small sample the results look OK. :)

Comment: No headphones. Some text-communicator instead? :) or skype via a mobile but really texting is what I prefere

Comment: atWilson, if You have mySQL 8+ running I can guide You on how to import the dataset (it takes likes a couple of minutes in total).

Comment: atWitek Will check in with you my tomorrow (Friday).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded bureau.csv and imported it using your table as shown in your 'part2' link. I had to disable strict mode

```
set session sql_mode='';)
```

else I got errors loading the data

```
(load data  infile 'bureau.csv' into table bureau columns terminated by "," ignore 1 lines;
```

My stats were slightly different than yours, though:
[image: show indexes from bureau]

I then ran your failing query and got expected results:

[image]

What exact version of MySQL 8 are you using?

Text version of the query:

```
select a.*
   from
   (
   select #b.sk_id_curr,
          b.*,
          count(*) over(partition by b.sk_id_curr)
   from (select * from bureau limit 10000000000) b
   ) a
   order by a.sk_id_curr desc
   limit 100
   ;
```

Comment: atDagW, according to my notes I used the file "https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb", the "Version" variable is 8.0.11

Comment: atDagW, pls look at my screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blz9d.png - cant post more links in the OP) - You can see columns with NULL (explicitly displayed) while on your screen there are blank spaces, what does that mean? :)

And whats the result of your "select count(*) from kag_home.bureau;"? mine 1716428

Comment: atDagW, I've added info on how I imported the file in the OP. I'll check your method, You can check mine.

Comment: atDagW, I tryied to copy your path but my results are still with an error... https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcZDk.png
I used "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" instead of your "LOAD DATA INFILE".

Comment: Still works OK with limited number of columns (b.sk_id_curr instead of b.*).

Comment: Thanks. Try if it works correctly if you replace the "text" type with, say, VARCHAR(20). "text" is a BLOB type in MySQL and there may be a bug there.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely check that, but tomorrow after work... :)

Comment: atDagW it didn't help, can You describe your path with more details? what mysql version? my.cnf? ... how many rows You have in the table?...

Comment: atDagW, and could You paste "EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON " for the query? :)

Comment: Hi Witold. I checked MySQL dev trunk (I am an MySQL dev); it seems you have hit an error in the product. I'll investigate further and report back. Thanks for your patience. I'm looking for a work-around also.

Comment: I was able to get correct result for MySQL version 8.0.11 if I modified the datatypes, cf. the queries below.